# Microsoft Excel : Best way to create a fixed template to manipulate, sort, convert data as well as calculate certain accruals based on select criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, templates

I have been given a task to create a working template in excel which converts our fortnightly payroll journal file from our payroll software into an accounting journal file so that we can upload this into our accounting software.
I have over 9 months worth of payroll data or 39+ journals to create.
At the moment I have to sort/arrange and manipulate the data over several spreadsheets to get at the solution I need. There are currently 3 states, 8 locations and 12 divisions all requiring their own separate journal codes.
Also, to complicate matters I require the payroll journal information to calculate accruals for taxes, insurances and unpaid wages based on a table of rates and then create additional accounting journals to ensure completeness of the payroll function on a monthly accounting basis.

Ideally, I want to be in a position to set up a master worksheet so that once I have it all working I can just upload the latest payroll journal and it does all of the calculations for me. Ultimately, I need to pass this task on to a junior clerk to undertake going forward without any requirement to mess around with any aspect of the spreadsheet.

What is the best way to approach this?

I see 4 main areas...

1. Manipulate the detailed payroll journal information so that it can be uploaded into the accounting software
2. Use the Gross wage element of the journal to calculate a payroll tax accrual for each state based on each states rate criteria, and create an accounting journal for uploading
3. Use the Payroll date to determine if an end of month accrual is required and if so calculate the gross pay accrual based on unpaid days using the gross wage element of the existing journal for uploading into the accounting software.
4. Use the same aspect of point 2 to calculate an insurance provision based on that states criteria, and create an accounting journal for upload.

I have watched numerous YouTube support videos but I cannot find one that sets up a dynamic worksheet to be overwritten and manipulated on a regular basis. Some weeks there may be 100 employees and other weeks there may be 150 employees so I need to create something that is adaptable.

Any help or guidance would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: That is a fairly big job.  One approach would be to bring the payroll file into a worksheet in a fixed format each time. Then in another worksheet, use VLOOKUP to formulate your payroll report and then input into your system.

Comment: What search query did you use to select videos on YouTube? Perhaps you were just looking in the wrong direction. Try adding "Power Query" to the search text - it is this tool that will allow you to [**collect data from different workbooks into a single table**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRuwX096qfQ), process the data as needed and store it to an Excel sheet in a form suitable for further processing. The script written in this way will always work - a junior clerk will only have to click the Update All button when he opens the workbook.

Comment: Power Query is definitely the way to go. Search for "merging tables in power query". Alternatively, if there is a lot of cosmetic adjustments to be made, moving of rows and columns, or other non-standard data processing, you might need to go the VBA route.